# Problems with sub items into a Joomla main menu item

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

I have a litle doubt related to main items and sub items in the Joomla Main Menù.

If you open this link you can easy understand my problem: http://onofri.org/example/example1/

In this website I have a main menu under the header. This main menu contains a main items named **Who We Are** which in turn contains 4 sub items that appear when you hover the mouse on the parent item (**Who We Are**)

Clicking on these sub item correctly appear some statics pages (some articles) and this is ok.

The problem appears if you click on the main iten **Who We Are**, in this case appear a **404 error**.

What can I do to solve this problem? Can I make not clickable the **Who we Are** main item?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

use "separator" as a menu kind; any other type will be clickable.

separator is available in the bottom group "System links" as "Text separator".

Comment: Ok, tnx...my only doubt is that if I use thee "Text Separator" type if I click on it the user is redirected to the homepage of the website, is it normal? TNX

Comment: no, possibly you are using a template override for the menu (i.e. there is a folder /templates/your_current_template/html/mod_menu ) which is handling separator wrong... if so, try renaming the folder (i.e. to mod_XXXmenu) and see if you get the expected "click" behaviour (main items not clickable, secondary items clickable); but of course you will be losing the customization / interactivity / dropdown effects since your template was designed with a custom override.  The menu override is extremely common, and should be fairly easy to fix.  If you paid for it, ask the developer to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

What I always do in such situations is avoiding using items that do not point to anywhere. It is better to do it like this:

- Make **Who We Are** a Article type menu item that will point to article from first sub-menu item in  **Who We Are**
- Make first submenu item **Erusma Birth** an Alias type menu item that will point to your main menu item **Who We Are**

What you have now is menu where all items point to some place on website. You have no errors and easy to understand navigation. Separator should not be used as main or sub-menu item it self. More like sub-menu column name etc.